# website log in using ms exchange account and laravel 4

Tags: email, authentication, laravel

I am newbie with laravel, I would like to build a simple website with authentication feature that use ms exchange account to validate user log in. So that every user should log in with their ms.exchange mail account and password.

Please help me, anybody ? Maybe there are some tutorials or examples out there.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that Exchange authenticates using LDAP; if so, there are quite a few Packagist packages you can tie into: https://packagist.org/search/?q=ldap

There's also a package specifically for LDAP in Laravel 4: https://github.com/ccovey/ldap-auth

Check out the github readme for details and examples.

Comment: Thank you Matt, Do you have any tutorial or examples about ldap auth by ccovey ? I have try to use ldap auth for laravel 4 by ccovey but failed.

Comment: This comment thread is pretty helpful: http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=11020